# is a streaming server necessary to play iPhone streaming video?

Tags: iphone

I am a noob with regards to this. I just wanted to know if a streaming server is necessary to play streaming videos on the iPhone.

e.g. I have a couple of mp4's hosted on a server. Can i play those files directly using MPMoviePlayerController with the URL http://xxxx.xx.mp4?

Are there any commercial solutions for hosting videos for the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play the file at url http://xxxx.xx.mp4 directly using MPMoviePlayerController, and it also does all streaming for you.

Comment: is this correct stream ? or ... how about the document HTTP live stream ? I see that too....